# SSRS/SQL Grouping the data as in PB report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

We are migrating the PB to SSRS report, in one report , they want to show the report as below format. basically sorting by dates column while retrieving, then apply group by customer name and it looks like below.

I am trying to achieve the same in SSRS through SSRS or using SQL.

```
        Vicky 
             2000-01-01 00:00:00.000    400

        SMART
             2001-01-01 00:00:00.000    600
             2001-01-01 00:00:00.000    900

        Rocky   
             2001-01-02 00:00:00.000

        Vicky   
            2002-01-01 00:00:00.000 200

        Rocky   
            2003-01-01 00:00:00.000 300
            2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 700
            2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 800

        SMART   
            2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 900


        Sample script. 

        Create table #Sample (CustomerName varchar(10),InvDate datetime, Invamount INT)

        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('Rocky','1/2/2001',100)
        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('Vicky','1/1/2002',200)
        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('Rocky','1/1/2003',300)
        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('Vicky','1/1/2000',400)
        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('SMART','1/1/2001',600)
        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('Rocky','1/1/2005',700)
        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('Rocky','1/1/2006',800)
        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('SMART','1/1/2001',900)
        Insert into #Sample (CustomerName,InvDate,Invamount) Values ('SMART','1/1/2010',900)

        SELECT * from #Sample
        ORDER BY InvDate
```